# Google Map not loading and no error in console

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps

I have set up my js and called the API functions as usual and yet the map ain't loading and the console displays no errors. Am I missing something?
My process is; I first collect the data from the database and house it in JSON which I then use in my map initialization.

js code

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" async></script>
<?php
/* lat/lng data will be added to this array */
$locations = array();
$findcluster = selectAll('input_cluster');
foreach ($findcluster as $cluster) {

    $nama_kabkot = $cluster['Name_of_cluster_Area'];
    $longitude = $cluster['Longitude'];
    $latitude = $cluster['Latitude'];

    /* Each row is added as a new array */
    $locations[] = array('name' => $nama_kabkot, 'lat' => $latitude, 'lng' => $longitude);
}
/* Convert data to json */
$markers = json_encode($locations);
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <?php
    echo "var markers=$markers;\n";

    ?>

    function initMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), myOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            marker, lat, lng;
        var json = JSON.parse(markers);

        for (var o in json) {

            lat = json[o].lat;
            lng = json[o].lng;
            name = json[o].name;

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                name: name,
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
                infowindow.setContent(this.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            }.bind(marker));
        }
    }
</script>
```

and my div tag

```
 <style>
                #mapCanvas {
                    width: 100%;
                    height:500px; 
                    margin: 0; 
                    padding: 0;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="card-body">
                
                    <canvas id="mapCanvas"></canvas>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: put some console.log's in various places inside the initMap function to see if it's a) being called, and b) doing anything

Comment: The `mapCanvas` element needs to be a `<div>` not a `<canvas>`

Comment: @geocodezip that's not the issue I have tried and that is not it. Have tried the posted answer below I switched API keys but it worked and stopped meaning the initial issue is the API key which I did not have anything to compare it with.

Comment: @Bravo I have tried doing that also, been debugging for hours might be the API key afterall

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) that exhibits the issue.  The `<canvas>` vs `<div>` is one issue.

Comment: so,in your hours of testing, does `initMap` get called at all? I thought what I was asking was pretty obvious

Answer (score 1):

The `mapCanvas` element needs to be a `<div>` not a `<canvas>`

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lknmyc2/1/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

```js
function initMap() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), myOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, lat, lng;
  var json = JSON.parse(markers);
  for (var o in json) {
    lat = json[o].lat;
    lng = json[o].lng;
    name = json[o].name;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      name: name,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    }.bind(marker));
  }
}
```

```css
#mapCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body, .card-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```